# Phonegap NFC Send and Read Data Between Two Devices

Tags: angular, nfc, ndef

I am trying to send information (just text) between two NFC enabled devices using phonegap-nfc in ionic angular app.

So far I am able to connect the devices and the Ndef Event Listener captures the tag, but the information in the tag is always the same, it does not give me the message I am sending.

My function to send the tag when NFC connection is identified:

```
 async connectPeerToPeer() {
    var listener = NFC.addNdefListener(onSucess => {
      console.log('Listening: ', onSucess);
    }, onFail => {
      console.log('Failure: ', onFail);
    }).subscribe(event => {
  
      NFC.share([Ndef.textRecord("hello world!")]).then(res => {
        this.service.Popup("The write message was sent!", ["OK"]);
      }).catch(err => {
        this.service.Popup("Error: "+ err, ["OK"]);
      });

    });
  }
```

My event to receive the tag:

```
   NFC.addNdefListener((listening) => {
      console.log("Listening");
    }, (fail) => {
      this.service.Popup(fail, ['OK']);
    }).subscribe(ev => {
      this.onNfc(ev);
    });

  onNfc(nfcEvent) {
    console.log(nfcEvent);
  }
```

With this the tag is transferred to the receiving device but the information is not the message I am sending.

This is what I get when I put a breakpoint on the inspector:

```
{"id":[0],"techTypes":["android.nfc.tech.Ndef"],"type":"android.ndef.unknown","maxSize":0,"isWritable":false,"ndefMessage":[{"tnf":1,"type":[85],"id":[],"payload":[3,112,108,97,121,46,103,111,111,103,108,101,46,99,111,109,47,115,116,111,114,101,47,97,112,112,115,47,100,101,116,97,105,108,115,63,105,100,61,105,111,46,105,111,110,105,99,46,115,116,97,114,116,101,114,38,102,101,97,116,117,114,101,61,98,101,97,109]},{"tnf":4,"type":[97,110,100,114,111,105,100,46,99,111,109,58,112,107,103],"id":[],"payload":[105,111,46,105,111,110,105,99,46,115,116,97,114,116,101,114]}],"canMakeReadOnly":false}
```

I am assuming my message could be inside `ndefMessage:`

But when I do `NFC.bytesToString(nfcEvent.tag.ndefMessage[0].payload)` I get the following string
`"play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.ionic.starter&feature=beam"`

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS version are you trying this on for each device?

Comment: Andrew, I am using a galaxy S9 Plus and a Huawei P30

Comment: OS: Android version 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because Android Beam (The functionality used in peer to peer NFC sharing) was deprecated in Android 10. (The OS is looking for an App to replace this missing feature).

See https://source.android.com/setup/start/android-10-release#nfc

Going forward it is probably better to use Wifi Direct or Bluetooth so send data between devices, Google were pushing their "Nearby" API https://developers.google.com/nearby/ as a replacement.

Comment: So NFC alone without Android Beam does not allow for such transfers or I could use NFC only while Beam is off?

Comment: So technically yes you can transfer data with NFC between 2 Android devices without Android Beam, normal NFC has an initiator (Active device) and target (mostly passive devices like NFC Tags). Luckily Android allows Host Card Emulation (HCE) mode where it pretends to be a "target" device. Thus you write a HCE service that pretends to be a type 4 card with the data on it and then the other devices reads it as if it was a normal type 4 tag. This is technically challenging to implement with lots of things to consider and would only work with both apps running in the foreground.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I was actually already reading on HCE and it might not an easy path but I am looking forward to implementing it. Appreciate your support

Comment: For the read of an emulated card I would recommend using `enableReaderMode` API https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle) to read, then because even if the older devices have Android Beam, it is disabled by this API (It's also just a much better and newer API to read Tags anyway).

Comment: Thank you Andrew, Yes, I am checking HCE with readerMode, I managed to emulate the card in the device and scan it using another device, now I am trying to use transceive to send raw commands to the HCE device, trying to understand that part in terms of what commands the HCE will accept to trigger the HCE.registerCommandCallback so that I can send some data back to the scanning device.

Comment: The HCE should respond to ISO7816-4 commands with some of the basic ones listed at https://cardwerk.com/smart-card-standard-iso7816-4-section-6-basic-interindustry-commands/ or should respond to the ones used for the NFC standard http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag_2.0.pdf  PS if the answer was correct please help other users and mark it as answered and or up vote it if it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I did upvote the answer as it was really helpful ... but it won't display because this is a new account. Will mark it as answered. Thank you for your support