# How to send an NDEF message from Android to another non-Adroid device

Tags: java, android, nfc, ndef

I'm trying to share a large (10-15 kB) string from my Android device to an ACR122u reader as an NDEF text record.

I've built a Phonegap hybrid app using the NFC plugin. The plugin provides **nfc.share()** method which executes the following code:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {

        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(getActivity());

        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            callbackContext.error(STATUS_NO_NFC);
        } else if (!nfcAdapter.isNdefPushEnabled()) {
            callbackContext.error(STATUS_NDEF_PUSH_DISABLED);
        } else {
            nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(p2pMessage, getActivity());
            nfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(NfcPlugin.this, getActivity());

            PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
            result.setKeepCallback(true);
            shareTagCallback = callbackContext;
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
        }
    });
```

As the plugin docs say:

```
Function nfc.share writes an NdefMessage via peer-to-peer. This should appear as an NFC tag to another device.
```

But neither my reader or any other Android device is unable to detect any NDEF data.

The ACR122u reader doesn't detect any NDEF data neither in reader or peer-to-peer mode.

While trying to share data with an Android device, it just activates Android Beam screen. I think the Android Beam prevents sharing NDEF messages until both devices are paired.

I've tried the official ACR reader SDK samples, PC/SC libraries for C#, but neither worked. My Android device is detected by the reader, but no NDEF data is present.

Comment: I've also tried other HCE, P2P and NDEF writers from Play Store, neither of them worked too.

Comment: Using `nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage` is Android Beam, so you would expect it to Activate the Android Beam screen on the receiving device. I found that trying to send data of less than 1Kb was too unreliable (It rarely worked) which is one of the reason why Google have deprecated this feature in Android 10. So P2P NFC is not a good way forward with Google dropping support and Apple never supporting it.

Comment: After reading some API docs, I've realized that too. Well, that makes plugin API docs quite confusing since it says "This should appear as an NFC tag to another device". It sounds like it will just emulate an NDEF-capable NFC tag.

Comment: Android Beam uses NFC Forum's SNEP (Simple NDEF Exchange Protocol), which is just basically a socket over NFC, it then generates an `Intent` that looks like it came from an the Android NFC Card reader System App reading a card after it has processed and read the card. Which is really just one App sending data to another, you cannot use the better `enableReaderMode` Tag reading API with this. There are some card readers that also support the right P2P mode but have to be programmed correct to do this. Only HCE will emulate a NFC tag.

Comment: So it is possible to send large string data using HCE?

Comment: See very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/64599128/2373819 it is possible but technically complicated, the asker of this question was making progress in doing a similar thing.