# Emulate Mifare/NFC tag using Ionic Angular

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, nfc, phonegap, hce

I have a Mifrare Ultralight card that I use for one reader. It can also read NFC smart cards. I need an Ionic - Angular app that behaves like the card / tag I have. It needs to send only specified ID - that's it - no data with it.

I went throgh lots of different docs and libs starting from [phonegap-nfc](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) ending up at [cordova-plugin-hce](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hce). I was sure it's enaugh that I only send Ndef messages using `phonegap-nfc` but it seems that

> Android Beam (The functionality used in peer to peer NFC sharing) was
> deprecated in Android 10

See https://source.android.com/setup/start/android-10-release#nfc

See [Phonegap NFC Send and Read Data Between Two Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599128/phonegap-nfc-send-and-read-data-between-two-devices)

It seems that HCE is my only choice now. But I cannot make it working. I've started to use `@ionic-native/hce` that is a wrapper for [cordova-plugin-hce](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hce). My code (through a lot of testing) looks like this:

```js
        hce.registerCommandCallback((command) => {
            console.log('COMMAND RECEIVED', command);

            const SAMPLE_LOYALTY_CARD_AID = 'F222222222';
            const SELECT_APDU_HEADER = '00A40400';


            // Format: [CLASS | INSTRUCTION | PARAMETER 1 | PARAMETER 2 | LENGTH | DATA]
            const aidByteLength = ('00' + (SAMPLE_LOYALTY_CARD_AID.length / 2).toString(16)).substr(-2);

            const SELECT_APDU = (SELECT_APDU_HEADER + aidByteLength + SAMPLE_LOYALTY_CARD_AID).toLowerCase();
            const SELECT_OK_SW = '9000';
            const UNKNOWN_CMD_SW = '0000';

            console.log(command);
            const commandAsBytes = new Uint8Array(command);
            const commandAsString = hce.util.byteArrayToHexString(commandAsBytes);

            console.log('received command ' + commandAsString);
            console.log('expecting        ' + SELECT_APDU);

            if (SELECT_APDU === commandAsString) {
                const accountNumberAsBytes = hce.util.stringToBytes('1234567890');
                const data = hce.util.concatenateBuffers(accountNumberAsBytes, hce.util.hexStringToByteArray(SELECT_OK_SW));

                console.log('Sending ' + hce.util.byteArrayToHexString(data));
                hce.sendResponse(data);
            } else {
                console.log('UNKNOWN CMD SW');
                hce.sendResponse(hce.util.hexStringToByteArray(UNKNOWN_CMD_SW));
            }
        }, (e) => {
            console.log('error mtf ', e);
        });

        hce.registerDeactivatedCallback(reason => {
            console.log('Deactivated ' + reason);
        });
```

The problem is that `registerCommandCallback` is never triggered when I move the phone close to the 13.56 Mhz reader. Any clue?

Comment: You need to show the code used to try and read the HCE emulated Type4 NFC Tag as it has to be trying to read the right Type of NFC card and must be trying to read the right AID number.

Comment: The reader is not an app. It's physical reader. For testing I use a standard 13.56Mhz reader like this: https://e-planeta.pl/userdata/public/gfx/1552.jpg (random img of device).

Comment: That USB reader will need software to control it to get to do anything and that software that is running on whatever is connected to USB cable needs to be programmed to read a Type4 Tag and then told to select the AID for the HCE you have written for `registerCommandCallback` to be fired (While you just want an ID you cannot use the Anti collision UID because on a phone this is randomly generated, so the ID has to be sent as data)